# Monthly count for each group from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The structure of table  "RAW_DATA" is like below  with given columns and a set of sample data is given

```
        ID  CompletedDate   TypeID  AgentID
        1   2015-09-22      51      301
        2   2015-08-6       50      301
        3   2015-07-12      50      305
        4   2017-04-21      51      305
        5   2015-05-5       51      305
        6   2016-09-8       50      301
        7   2015-02-17      50      301
        8   2015-01-12      51      311
        9   2015-10-4       50      311
        10  2015-12-2       51      311
```

Using the below query i am able to get the total count for a month from this table

```
     SELECT FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy') as Date,datepart(year,CompletedDate) YearNr,datepart(month,CompletedDate) MonthNr,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID=50 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Type1",
         COUNT(CASE WHEN  TypeID=51 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Type2"
         FROM RAW_DATA
         group by  datepart(year,CompletedDate),datepart(month,CompletedDate),  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
```

The sample result i got is looks like

```
        Date            YearNr  MonthNr Type1   Type2
        September 2016  2016    9       12282   224
        October 2015    2015    10      54      0
        November 2017   2017    11      5535    65
        March 2017      2017    3       1669    5641
        December 2016   2016    12      772     39
```

Now i have to do an additional grouping against the column "AgentID" on a monthly basis .  So the result set should be like for each Agent , the count for each month based on the above conditions

And i tried to add  the column "AgentID" in select and group by sections of above query , like below

```
        SELECT AgentID,FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy') as Date,datepart(year,CompletedDate) YearNr,datepart(month,CompletedDate) MonthNr,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID=50 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Type1",
         COUNT(CASE WHEN  TypeID=51 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Type2"
         FROM RAW_DATA
         group by  AgentID, datepart(year,CompletedDate), datepart(month,CompletedDate), FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
```

But the generated output is like

```
        Date        AgentID YearNr  MonthNr Type1   Type2
        April 2016      3642    2016    4   21  39
        November 2016   2887    2016    11  1   0
        March 2017      2309    2017    3   0   24
        May 2017        2784    2017    5   1   24
        December 2017   3355    2017    12  2   0
```

This is not the expected result . For example  for each Agent there must be an entry for all the months in the result set

```
Agent1  April2016 
Agent1 Nov 2017
Agent1 Dec 2016
```

now for Agent2

```
Agent2  April2016 
Agent2 Nov 2017
Agent2 Dec 2016
```

So how can i get the monthly count for each Agents??

Comment: You've got too many rep points to think "but not worked." is an acceptable problem description.

Comment: Come on, at least show us the code that didn't work AND tell us exactly how it didn't work. You were so clear and detailed about what DID work, but vague and lacking any detail about your actual problem?

Comment: Please add the desired output, how do you want to integrate the count for each month for each agent with your existing query where you are grouping by different format??

Comment: please see the edited parts with more details about what i tried and the result i am getting with that and what should be the expected result

Answer (score 2):

You just need to group by `agentId` and month_year:

```
SELECT 
  AgentID,
  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy') as MonthYear,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID=50 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Type1",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN  TypeID=51 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Type2",
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM RAW_DATA
group by  AgentID, FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab34b/8)

Answer (score 0):

Just add  Count(*) as "monthelyAgentcount" in your query ie

```
 SELECT AgentID,FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy') as Date,datepart(year,CompletedDate) YearNr,datepart(month,CompletedDate) MonthNr,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN TypeID=50 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Type1",
     COUNT(CASE WHEN  TypeID=51 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Type2" ,
     Count(*) as "monthelyAgentcount"
     FROM RAW_DATA
     group by  AgentID,datepart(year,CompletedDate),datepart(month,CompletedDate),  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
```